# How to get the count of deleted entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I use the following method to delete a set of objects based on a certain where condition, but in reality the number of removed objects could be lesser than the passed collection. How do I get the actual count of deleted entities

[http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html#deleteAll(java.util.Collection)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html#deleteAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

Comment: Do a COUNT with the same WHERE clause before and after executing the DELETE command?

Comment: @DanTemple would not work with a busy DB server

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yeah, there'll be time delays in the requests, so the data might not be entirely accurate on a high traffic system. Hence I put it as a comment, with a question mark on the end. Depending on the system as a whole, it could be an adequate solution.

Comment: Sorry @DanTemple I did not notice the `?`

Comment: @ScaryWombat No hassle :) I should have made my point a little clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You can build a query based on primary keys `DELETE FROM ... WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)` or something similar and then use `executeUpdate()` method which returns the number of affected rows.